# Displaying Wordpress Header on all pages, not just Front Page

Tags: php, wordpress

Looking for help in getting my wordpress theme to display header image on all pages and not just the home page as it currently does. All pages use get_header php command and the header.php contains the following code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The header for our theme
 *
 * This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
 *
 * @package Superb_Landingpage
 */

?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
        <?php wp_body_open(); ?>

    <div class="navigation-wrapper">
        
        <div class="site grid-container">
            <header id="masthead" class="site-header grid-x grid-padding-x">
                <div class="site-branding large-4 medium-10 small-9 cell">
                    <?php
                    the_custom_logo();
                    if ( is_front_page() && is_home() && is_page() ) :
                        ?>
                    <div class="logo-container">
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                        <?php
                        else :
                            ?>
                        <div class="logo-container">
                            <h2 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php
                            endif;
                            $superb_landingpage_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
                            if ( $superb_landingpage_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                                ?>
                            <p class="site-description"><?php echo $superb_landingpage_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>  
                </div><!-- .site-branding -->

                <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation large-8 medium-2 small-3 cell">

                    <?php
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                        'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                        'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
                        ) );
                        ?>
                    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
                </header><!-- #masthead -->
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
        <?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>

    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="bottom-header-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url(( get_header_image()) ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr(( get_bloginfo( 'title' )) ); ?>" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
        <div id="page" class="site grid-container start-container-head">
            <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'superb-landingpage' ); ?></a>
            <div id="content" class="site-content grid-x grid-padding-x">
```

What do I add/remove to simply have the header display on all pages?

I've tried removing the if/else conditions in the header.php but wordpress keeps rolling back the edit claiming errors. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include all of the `header.php` file? At the moment, it's not clear what's going on after the `if` condition. Also `the_custom_logo` function is outside of the `if` condition! I don't think your logo has anything to do with the `if` condition. It's not clear until you add the entire or at least the relevant sections of your `header.php` file.

Comment: Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```

If this does not work try this

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    // This is a homepage
} else {
    // This is not a homepage
}
?>
```